# map angular2 : Argument types does not match parameters

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make an http request and perform map.

I followed angular docs but for some reason i'm getting an error on the **map** function: "Argument types do not match parameters". Please notice i've imported `'rxjs/add/operator/map';`.

Should I need to `npm install` something ?

I'm using `Angular 4.0.2`, `rxjs 5.0.1` and `WebStorm 2016.1.3` and here is my code:

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class ApiService {

      constructor(private http: Http) {
      }

      public getValue() : Observable<any> {

       return this.http.get('')
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

      }

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

for some reason: changing to `.map().map(this.extractData)` solved the issue.
here is `map.d.ts` definition:

```
import { map } from '../../operator/map';
declare module '../../Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        map: typeof map;
    }
}
```

I would be happy if someone can explain why.

**UPDATE 2:**

revert to `.map(this.extractData)` without `.map()` seem to work when running the project ! Probably it's an error generated by webstorm IDE.

Comment: your solution is a bad idea.... Typescript compiler errors are generally warnings that you might be mixing things that you aren't being explicit about mixing.  Are you sure your error is with the original `map` function?  if you remove the `map` does the error go away?  or if you change your extractData function temporarily to accept `any` as its parameter, does the Typescript error go away?

Comment: @snorkpete if I remove map() then I'm getting an error. in addition, changing extract data to accept "res : any" instead of "res : Response" still produces the same error

Comment: When you remove the `map`, are you getting the same (original) error or a different one?

Comment: @snorkpete the same error but please refer to UPDATE 2

Comment: OH...  you didn't mention the error coming from WebStorm. WebStorm messes up its errors surprisingly often. Every once in a while, i invalidate caches and restart so it can rebuilt its indices.  If you see a WebStorm Typescript error, try building your project (from the command line) to see if the official Typescript compiler gives the same error. If the latter doesn't complain, it's WebStorm acting up again.  WebStorm is still totally worth it, but it does get its errors confused often enough.

Comment: @snorkpete thanks man.. do u know how to fix it in webstorm? p.s building won't help to remove it from webstorm

Comment: WebStorm has a menu option: "Invalidate caches and restart". On the mac, this is under the 'File' menu. It will cause WebStorm to rescan your project and hopefully clear up any of those weird errors it is currently displaying

Answer (score 0):

You sure the error is on the `map` statement?

IMO this line:

```
return this.http.get('')
```

would throw an error because of the missing URL (`''`) and this will be invoked instead:

```
.catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

If this is the problem, then check the signature of `Observable.throw`, it expects an exception as first parameter. I think it should be:

```
.catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(new Error(error.json().error || 'Server error')));
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying any input parameters to `extractData`. Change to `.map((data) => this.extractData(data))` or something along that line.

Comment: Change res: Response to res: any on extractData and see if it helps.

Comment: still doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, I'm very confused - it you seem to have found the root of the problem. Good it worked out.